# Pay with least change Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, payment, currency

I'm trying to guide my users with making cash payments. Let's say the user has two 200 dollar bills, one 100 dollar bill, one 50 dollar bill, two 10 dollar bills and three 5 dollar bill.

The user wants to pay amount of 61. The function should tell the user to pay with the bills that require the least change. This means the function should tell the user to pay with one 50, one 10 and one 5. The user will receive a change of 4.

```js
function payWithLeastChange(amount, bills) {
  let billQuantities = organizeBills(bills);
  billQuantities.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value); // sort bills in ascending order

  let result = [];
  for (const bill of billQuantities) {
    while (amount >= bill.value && bill.quantity > 0) {
      let foundBill = result.find((b) => b.value === bill.value);
      if (foundBill) {
        foundBill.quantity++;
      } else {
        result.push({ value: bill.value, quantity: 1 });
      }
      amount -= bill.value;
      bill.quantity--;
    }
  }

  if (amount > 0) {
    return "Error: Not enough bills to make the payment.";
  }

  return { payment: result, change: amount };
}

function organizeBills(bills) {
  let billQuantities = [];
  let billValues = Array.from(new Set(bills));

  for (const billValue of billValues) {
    billQuantities.push({
      value: billValue,
      quantity: bills.filter((bill) => bill === billValue).length,
    });
  }

  return billQuantities;
}

let amount = 61;
let bills = [200, 100, 100, 100, 50, 50, 50, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10, 10, 5, 5, 5];
let payment = payWithLeastChange(amount, bills);
console.log(payment);
```

I call the function like so:

```
let amount = 61;
let bills = [200, 100, 100, 100, 50, 50, 50, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10, 10, 5, 5, 5];
let payment = payWithLeastChange(amount, bills);
console.log(payment);
```

I'm expecting an output of

```
{ payment: [
  { value: 50, quantity: 1 },
  { value: 10, quantity: 1 },
  { value: 5, quantity: 1 }
],
change: 4 }
```

but instead am getting "Error: Not enough bills to make the payment." I'm stuck and can't figure out what to change in the function.

Comment: `while (amount >= bill.value` never goes below `amount` 0 (i.e. 'can afford it').

Comment: @RickardElimää, I am going to rollback that change, as you removed the user's code and only left the ChatGPT code. Surely we will concentrate on the user's code, no?

Comment: I think it's disrespectful to ask us to debug AI code that you can't understand, so in order to make the post more specific, I removed it and left your original code. You should also debug your code to see what happens in each iteration. Add a `console.log({result}, {amount})` in the loop.

Comment: @trincot I removed the AI code. As the post clearly states `I am adding the pre chatGPT function below:`, and that was the code I left in the post.

Comment: @RickardElimää, then you made a mistake, because I found the ChatGPT code in the snippet, not the user's code.

Comment: @trincot Sorry to say, but I think you made the mistake. I moved the code around in my edit. The original code written by the user is refactored, while the AI code has all the code in one method.

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea behind the code is faulty to begin with, but I can give you some pointers along the way.

What's messing up your code is the line `while (amount >= bill.value && bill.quantity > 0) {` where you will only add up bills that are lower than the value. But you can get a change on $100. In fact, below are possible combinations that renders change to $63.

200 (a change of $137)
100
50+50
50+20
50+10+10
50+10+5
50+5+5+5
20+20+20+10
20+20+20+5
20+20+10+10
20+20+10+5
20+10+10+10+5
20+10+10+5+5+5

So what you need is to find all these combinations (and more), and then find a combination that have a) the least amount of change, but also b) the least amount of bills, i.e. 50+10+5.

You don't need `organizeBills()`. It's better to just work with the `bills` array, but you will need to loop through that array multiple times in one way or another.